# Are there any differences in implementation between Okta's SAML Java Toolkit and OpenSAML?

Tags: saml, opensaml, okta, okta-api

I am currently integrating SAML with a custom Java web-app in order to put it behind Okta. I want to use the SAML Java Toolkit that is provided by Okta.

There are many examples on the internet of OpenSAML implementations in order for me to get a general idea of how to begin. However, I am wondering if there are any significant differences between OpenSAML and the SAML Toolkit provided by Okta.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSAML is a set of open source C++ & Java **libraries** meant to support developers working with the SAML protocol. The current version supports SAML 1.0, SAML1.1, and SAML2.0 protocols. In other words,  OpenSAML is a library for handling the low level SAMLx.x protocol implementations.

SAML Toolkits are mostly free and open-source, designed to shorten the development time and reduce the complexity to implement SAML2.0 enabled web-apps.

SAML Java Toolkits from Okta uses OpenSAML Java libraries to implement minimal features of SAML2.0 protocol for vendors to quickly deploy SAML Service Provider (SP) server and protect their web-apps. Otherwise, vendor has to employ developers who has to know and understand SAML2.0 specification and then use OpenSAML or other similar libraries to implement SAML2.0 protocol to protect their web-apps.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!